# Flutter Firebase Sign In with Apple not returning email in firebase auth user

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Im integrating Sign in with Apple and everything works fine and users can sign in just fine.  But when I look at the record in the firebase authentication it doesnt save the users email to the firebase user after authenticating.  So then I cant save it to the user database and use it like I do with the google sign in.  Here is my sign in code:

```
 @override
  Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithApple({List<Scope> scopes = const []}) async {
    final AuthorizationResult result = await AppleSignIn.performRequests(
        [AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: [Scope.email])]);
    switch (result.status) {
      case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        final appleIdCredential = result.credential;
        final oAuthProvider = OAuthProvider(providerId: 'apple.com');
        final credential = oAuthProvider.getCredential(
          idToken: String.fromCharCodes(appleIdCredential.identityToken),
          accessToken:
          String.fromCharCodes(appleIdCredential.authorizationCode),
        );

        final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        final firebaseUser = authResult.user;
        updateDatabase(firebaseUser);
        return firebaseUser;
      case AuthorizationStatus.error:
        throw PlatformException(
          code: 'ERROR_AUTHORIZATION_DENIED',
          message: result.error.toString(),
        );
      case AuthorizationStatus.cancelled:
        throw PlatformException(
          code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
          message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
        );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to change ```Scope.email``` with ```AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email```?

Comment: working with flutter and the apple_sign_in plugin doesnt have that variable

Comment: try using sign_in_with_apple package instead